# Use massive javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

Help me please. I have problems with sending variables from javascript to HTML form.

Here is my script :

```
<script>
function PopUpShow5(main_id, id, description, data_date, end_date, priority, status){
    $("#popup5").show();
    var elements = [main_id, id, description, data_date, end_date, priority, status]

    document.getElementById("id_get_post_pk").innerHTML = elements[0];
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_id").innerHTML = elements[1];
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_description").innerHTML = elements[2];
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_start_date").innerHTML = elements[3];
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_end_date").innerHTML = elements[4];
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_priority").innerHTML = elements[5];
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_status").innerHTML = elements[6];

    $(document).keyup(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 27)
        $("#popup5").hide();
    });
}
function PopUpHide5(){
    $("#popup5").hide();
}
</script>
```

Here is the part where I send variables(I'm working with Django) :

```
<div style="width:5%; float:right;">        
     <div id="b-container">
          <div class="photo" data-title="Edit"><a href="javascript:PopUpShow5({{ item.main_id }}, {{ item.id }}, &quot;{{ item.description }}&quot;, &quot;{{ item.data_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}&quot;, &quot;{{ item.end_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}&quot;, {{ item.priority }}, {{ item.status }})"><input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/edit.png" border="0" width="17" height="17" ></a></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

But in the use my variables I have problems, I can use only the first variable from script (in this case `id_get_post_pk`), but i need use all them. How I can do this?

In textarea i can set id (and value) only the first element, but I need description (when i put the variable `id_get_post_description` in the top, im witout any problems can use them but not other)
form :

```
<div class="b-popup" id="popup5" >
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        <form action="" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
            <input id="id_get_post_id" value="id_get_post_id" type="hidden" maxlength="9999" name="get_post_id" type="text">
            <label for="id_description_post" style=" display:table; margin-top:0px; padding-left:13px;">Description :<br></label>
            <textarea id="id_get_post_id" maxlength="9999" name="id_get_post_status" style="resize:none; font-size: 12pt;" rows="12" cols="67" autofocus onkeyup="enableField(this.form,this.value)" type="text"></textarea><br>
            <center>
                <input type="submit" name="bttnsubmit" value="Apply" ONCLICK="window.location.href='/'" disabled="true" style="height:30px; width:80px;" >
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" ONCLICK="PopUpHide5()" style="height:30px; width:80px" >
            </center>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the any help.

Comment: If you use jquery for your selectors, why then don't for getting the values?

Comment: Why are you putting all your variables into an array? Why not assign directly from the variables?

Comment: This document.getElementById("id_get_post_pk").value = elements[0]; did not resolve my problems =(

Comment: I can't asign directly values, because their changing all times in cycle and form "popup5" i'm was put from outside the cycle.

Comment: Do you mean, you have an array. Inside the array, you have a description. You want to populate the description inside your `textarea`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `.innerHTML` to set `<input>` element values. Use `.value`, instead:

```
document.getElementById("id_get_something").value = elements[number];
```

(For a `<textarea>`, `.innerHTML` is the way to go, though.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is did not resolve my problem =(